# Why Actionbar should be hidden if we are hiding the Statusbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

Eventhough its possible to hide the Status bar while keeping the Action bar the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) emphasises

> "You should never show the action bar without the status bar."

What is the reason for this? Is it just a UX guideline or are there other reasons for it?